# Is it better to file.write() or to print to file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files

To write to a file called "file.txt", I can either use:

```
with open('file.txt', 'a') as file:
    file.write('some text')
```

or :

```
with open('file.txt', 'a') as file:
    print('some text', file=file)
```

What are the advantages/disadvantages of each? Are they essentially the same?

Comment: Which is more descriptive of what you're trying to accomplish? My money is on the one that says what it's doing in the method name rather than redirecting print from STDOUT to a file handle....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are they essentially the same?

No.  The second code block will append a new line in the output, the first won't.

> What are the advantages/disadvantages of each?

`print` has more features.  It allows you to use non-string objects, *args with custom separators, etc.

If all you are doing is writing/printing a single string, then there is not much difference and no particular reason to choose one over the other.  But do be aware of the trailing newline in the print (i.e. the default `end` argument of the print function).